# Cannot see most extensions in Nbextensions tab in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I installed Nbextensions using

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

The installation was fine and I can also see Nbextensions tab on my jupyter notebook. However I see only a few extensions, the ones in image below [missing extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkgYY.png)

I followed the same process on macbook and it worked fine. How do I get this to show other extensions like Hinterland, codefolding etc.?

Comment: This [page](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#conda) says that using `jupyter contrib nbextension install --sys-prefix` automatically installs the Javascript and CSS files, so the second installation step below can therefore be skipped.

Answer (score 9):

Ok I was able to resolve this. Just ran the line below in addition

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

and it worked!